# Creating register variable arrays with CudaFy

Tags: cudafy.net

My CUDA kernel would run much faster if instead of a shared memory array (L1) I was able to use thread register memory.

I can do this in CUDA-C with the following declaration:

```
unsigned short window[15];
```

but in C# when I try:

```
ushort[] window = new ushort[15];
```

I get a run-time error about not being able to create arrays in CudaFy. I don't want a global memory array, or a shared memory. (which are most of the discussion issues). I am running with SM35 architecture.

```
Array create expressions are not supported.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Cudafy currently doesn't support creating thread local arrays, so doing this through Cudafy is currently not possible.

You could do it the manual way and force Cudafy to use a manually edited version of the generated Cuda C code:

```
CudaGPU gpu = (CudaGPU)CudafyHost.GetDevice(eGPUType.Cuda, 0);
CompileProperties prop = new CompileProperties()
    {
        Platform = ePlatform.x64,
        Architecture = eArchitecture.sm_50, 
        CompileMode = eCudafyCompileMode.Default,
        CompilerPath = @"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\nvcc", 
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Path\To\Project\bin\Debug", 
        TimeOut = 60000,
        IncludeDirectoryPath = @"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\include",
    };

CudafyModule module = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(prop, typeof(YourClass));
```

To make sure it will use the modified code file instead of the code file generated by the call to `CudafyTranslator.Cudafy()`, the architecture must be set higher than the previous.

```
prop.Architecture = eArchitecture.sm_52; 
prop.InputFile = @"ModifiedCudaSource.cu";
```

The file specified in `InputFile` must be in `WorkingDirectory`

Finally, add the modified source file to the module, compile the new PTX, and load the module:

```
module.AddSourceCodeFile(new SourceCodeFile(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(prop.WorkingDirectory, prop.InputFile), Encoding.Default), eLanguage.Cuda, prop.Architecture));
module.Compile(prop);

gpu.LoadModule(module);
```

I'm not entirely sure if you even need to call `CudafyTranslator.Cudafy()` to get the module, but this is working for me and I only run this code once, so cba to do further testing :)

Comment: Would it not just be simpler to use the [CudafyDummy] attribute and then write this in straight CUDA-C? (P.S. I think I Nick Kopp interested in adding this to CudaFy) But more votes would help.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the [CudafyDummy] option. That seems somewhat easier - at least easier to manage! Thanks!